# C++ - Accessing a file that was "dropped" on the executable

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

I have used a number of programs where I am able to use the programs functions by simply dragging and dropping a file onto the executable. For example, if there is a program that formats text files, simply dragging a text file onto the executable will make it run and use the text file as the target.

What does the main function look like for a program that allows this?

Comment: Maybe such programs accept file names as their first command line argument? Did you try this?

Comment: You should tag this with the appropriate OS (I assume Windows?) since it's really very little to do with c++

Comment: @therefromhere Yes. This is Windows. My apologies that I did not include it initially.

Comment: No worries - you can edit your post to add that to the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dropped files are usually just given as command line parameters to the program:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     if (argc > 1)
     {
         // do sth. with argv[1]  ==  first dropped file name
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to a school where we have never learned about these initial parameters. Was always void main(). Thank you so much!